# Image in Laravel 5 is not working

Tags: php, image, laravel

I am working with image in Laravel 5. I use folklore package of Laravel 5. it works fine for store but shows problem while updating image.

**ArticleController:**

```
$article_to_update = $article->find($id);
$uploaded_image = $request->file('image_file');
$parameter = $request->all();

if (isset($uploaded_image))
{

    $ext = $uploaded_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $newImageName = $article_to_update->id . "." . $ext;

    $uploaded_image->move(
        base_path() . '/public/uploads/article/', $newImageName
    );
    Image::make(base_path() . '/public/uploads/article/' . $newImageName, array(
        'width'  => 170,
        'height' => 120,
    ))->save(base_path() . '/public/uploads/article/' . $newImageName);
    $parameter = $request->all();
    $parameter['image'] = $newImageName;
    unset($parameter['image_file']);
    $article_to_update->update($parameter);

} else
{

    $article_to_update->update($parameter);
}


Session::flash('message', 'The article was successfully edited!.');
Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-success');
return redirect('articles');
}
```

**Edit.blade.php:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><b>IMAGE</b></label>
    {!! Form::file('image_file',null,array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'file_uploader')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('image',null,array('class'=>'form-control','id'=> 'file-name')) !!}
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \App\Auth;

/**
 * Class Article
 * @package App
 */
class Article extends Model {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

problem shows when i put a image too in the field..

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image_file' in 'field list' 
(SQL: update `articles` set `updated_at` = 2015-08-20 07:15:14, 
`image_file` = afc-logo.gif where `id` = 457)
```

Anyone help?

Comment: "shows problem while updating image"... what is the problem?

Comment: Unknown column 'image_file'

Comment: Either you haven't whitelisted the `image_file` column in your model, or you don't have a column in your database table called `image_file`.

Answer (score 0):

The above code was not working because in edit form, `encrypt/multipart` is not used for image or any file..
so I used `file=true` that solved my problem..

```
{!! Form::model($article,['method' => 'PATCH','route'=> ['articles.update',$article->id],'files' => true]) !!}
```

This solves the whole updating image problem...